# operating system loops variable stack question

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operating-system

```
cout << "blah blah blah";
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
 cout << '#' << endl;;
}
cout << "blah blah blah";
```

is the integer i on the stack frame? if the integer can only be used in the loop, how does the operating system keep track of what variables can only be used in the loop and not in the entire function?

Answer (score 4):

The operating system doesn't have anything to do with it - it's the compiler's job.

Any decent system will keep i in a cpu register

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` is almost certainly placed in a register in this case.

It is the compiler, not the operating system, which enforces the rule that the variable is accessible only within the loop.  (It is a compile time rule, not a run time rule.)